# Select sql query to group by nested json

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, database

The data I am getting from select query is something like this

```
[{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE456',
  products: '[{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6B7"}]',
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
}, ... ]
```

What I am doing is fetching `orders` and then parsing `products` attribute and extracting `product_id` and counting the number of time the product_id occured in the number of different json objects. 
This would be very time consuming if number of rows to fetch are in thousands and then extracting ids and counting its occurrences. 
Is there any effective way to use `GROUP by` and get directly occurrences of `product_id`  for thousands of rows.

Comment: value of the products should be an array/object instead of a string. i.e. [{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE456',
  products: [{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6B7"}],
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
}, ... ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use it!

```
var data = [{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE451',
  products: [{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6B7"}],
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
},{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE452',
  products: [{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6B7"},{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6K7"}],
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
},{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE453',
  products: [{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6K7"}],
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
},{
  id: 'CB2FD8B7-7E6D-4BF3-8E73-70D41FFBE454',
  products: [{"product_id":"22061DA1-5D64-475A-B36A-140ECFE8D6B7"}],
  falconpay_api_response: null,
  dhl_updated_by: null
}];
var a =[];
data.forEach(function(order){
    order.products.forEach(function(product){
    if(a[product.product_id] == undefined){
        a[product.product_id] = [];
    }
    a[product.product_id].push(order);
  })
});
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Query (That's only works in JSON data type) :-

```
SELECT products->>'$.product_id' products, 
      count(products)
FROM events
GROUP BY products->>'$.product_id';
```

And Following Link will helpful to you :-

[http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/]

Comment: The OP specified SQL-Server not MySQL.  Hopefully this will help the next person who stumbles here...